# pam_open_session: Module is unknown

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, pam, 20.10

I am using `Ubuntu 20.10` in `WSL`, and there are problems with changing the `ulimit -n`. I tried several methods and one of them needed to add `session required pam_limits.so` line to the `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` and `/etc/pam.d/common-session` files. After that i can't use `sudo` anymore. Same error all the time:

```bsh
sudo: pam_open_session: Module is unknown
sudo: policy plugin failed session initialization
```

`su` mode also not work too:

```bsh
nosheyakku@DESKTOP-GL13L32:/mnt/c/Users/nosheyakku$ su
Password:
su: Authentication failure
```

Attempt to change password:

```bsh
nosheyakku@DESKTOP-GL13L32:/mnt/c/Users/nosheyakku$ passwd
Changing password for kshnkvn.
Current password:
New password:
Retype new password:
Password unchanged
New password:
Retype new password:
Password unchanged
New password:
Retype new password:
Password unchanged
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

```bsh
nosheyakku@DESKTOP-GL13L32:/mnt/c/Users/nosheyakku$ sudo whoami
[sudo] password for kshnkvn:
sudo: pam_open_session: Module is unknown
sudo: policy plugin failed session initialization
```

Comment: You will probably need to invoke your wsl instance as root (`wsl -u root`) and revert your changes from there