# Sudo command is not asking password from stdin. And Failing

Tags: 18.04, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pipe

Whenever I am running any command with sudo, No password is asked from stdin.
Instead, it automatically takes a password from somewhere and fails.
Once All attempts are exhausted, my command is ultimately failed.
I am not able to open the sudoers file too.

I also tried `echo PASSWORD | sudo ls`.
Here too it is taking the wrong password.

```
ank@ank-aqua-pc:server$type -a sudo
sudo is /usr/bin/sudo

ank@ank-aqua-pc:server$sudo -l
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead. Add the output of `type -a sudo` and `sudo -l` to the question too.

Comment: A temporary workaround may be `pkexec`, I haven't found any solution so this command is temporary.

Comment: This answer should help https://superuser.com/a/1358225

Comment: Does your user have an empty password? see for example [sudo for users with empty passwords](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139589/sudo-for-users-with-empty-passwords)

Answer (score 1):

The `man sudo` is saying ([Source](https://superuser.com/a/1358225))

> -S, --stdin Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the standard input instead of using the terminal device. The password must be followed by a newline character.

and you need to specify the user that this password is used for

The correct command is

```
PASSWORD="abc\n" #The \n is for newline character
echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S -u <username> <command
```

Comment: `ank@ank-aqua-pc:aquasec$echo $PASSWD | sudo -S -u ank ls`

`sudo: pam_open_session: Module is unknown
sudo: policy plugin failed session initialization`
This replied with error pam_open_session.: Module unknown. 
Looks like some one was stuck with same issue but did not get fix. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291697/pam-open-session-module-is-unknown